# How do I stop execution of a AWS Lambda after a callback?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a Lambda behind an API and want to respond with an error if the right parameters are not provided. I can send a message with a callback, but is there a way to stop execution when I send the message?
I attach a sample code:

```
    dynamodb.putItem(add_params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) callback(null,respond({Success:{BOOL:false},Error{S:JSON.stringify(err)}}));
     if (data==null) callback(null,respond({Success:{BOOL:false},Error:{S:"No data in previous step"}}));
     callback(null,respond(return_JSON));
    });
```

I would have expected the Lambda to terminate when it responds but instead I am getting several callbacks

Comment: Answer below by Yogesh completely solved my problem. Though callback returned but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are calling the "callback" method and then continuing.  Basically your `if` check for error evaluates to true, the callback is called, but the code will continue onto the next if where you check for `data == null` and so on.

```
dynamodb.putItem(add_params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        callback(null, respond({ Success: { BOOL: false }, Error{ S: JSON.stringify(err) } }));
    } else if (data == null) {
        callback(null, respond({ Success: { BOOL: false }, Error: { S: "No data in previous step" } }));
    } else {
        callback(null, respond(return_JSON));
    }
});
```

The other way to do it is to return after the callback. So do this:

```
if (err){
  callback(params),
  return;
}
```

This will cause you program control to return from the callback that you had passed to dynamodb.putItem.